# Have I misunderstood how to use the abline function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot some lines using plot() and abline()

My code:

```
o = seq(1,100)
p = seq(1,100)

plot(o, p, type='n')
abline(v=5, lty=2) # o>=5
abline(2*p, p, lty=2) #o<2p
abline(o, (36-o*1.5), lty=2) #p<=36-o*1.5
```

This gives me a graph that looks like this:

[image: Chart with wrong line]

The line closest to 0 on the 'o' axis should be negative with respect to 'o' but it appears to be slightly positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to pass a vector of values to `abline`. In your case, `abline` just picks off the first elements of each vector to act as intercept and slope for the line.

To see this, I modify your code slightly to index `o` and `(36-o*1.5)` and only use the first elements using `[1]`. The result is the same (with solid line now).

```r
o = seq(1,100)
p = seq(1,100)

plot(o, p, type='n')
abline(v=5, lty=2) # o>=5
abline(2*p, p, lty=2) #o<2p
abline(o[1], (36-o*1.5)[1]) #p<=36-o*1.5
```

[image]